# Как в django сделать денежное поле в модели?

Tags: python, django

Варианты типа "хранить в int и при выводе делить на 100" просьба не предлагать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield)

Comment: невероятно что вы поняли что такое денежное поле))

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовый модуль для этого — Django Money.

https://github.com/django-money/django-money